# WebSocket connection error using socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Trying to run node.js and socket.io for the first time but I'm keep getting this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 
'ws://localhost:8080/socket.io/1/websocket/1826726211257272865'   
failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

in every example what I try and I can't figure out why. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I didn't installed the express web framework.